# Syntax Checking for CoffeeScript

Tags: ide, coffeescript

I searched google and i didn't found an IDE that would allow Syntax Checking specifically.
Is there a way to check syntax in VS or other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 on vim-coffee-script and syntastic.

Have you checked CoffeeScript's [wiki](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Text-editor-plugins)? There are few plugins that add syntax checking:

- [CoffeeScript plugin for sublime](https://github.com/Xavura/CoffeeScript-Sublime-Plugin)
- [CoffeeScript for Netbeans](https://github.com/dstepanov/coffeescript-netbeans)

You might be interested in using a command line tool like [CoffeeLint](http://www.coffeelint.org/), which offers optional validation rules. You can add it to your development process writing your own script to watch for changes in files or using tools like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: How do you actually setup Xavura for Sublime Text on Windows Platform?

Answer (score 3):

Even though not free, [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) comes with good support for Coffeescript out of the box.

By far the IDE I prefer most developing Coffe/Javascript at the moment.

Comment: I agree. Syntax Checking & Highlighting.

Comment: Not to forget it comes with really good coding support including an Autocompletion I couldn't find in other IDEs yet.

Answer (score 1):

See [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php), and install this [plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) for syntax checkong, and [this one](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) for syntax coloring.

This is a lightweight, scalable, and cheap option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using Vim, just add the [vim-coffee-script](https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) and [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you're into Emacs, there's an [Emacs major mode for CoffeeScript](https://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode).

Here is the [blog post](http://ozmm.org/posts/coffee_mode.html) announcing its release.